# Windows 10-Python Pip Install pyinstaller error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, windows-10

I had this error when i tried to do: pip install pyinstaller.

So please help me with this error i got because i have been searching for ages to fix this error.

The error line when i tried to install **pyinstaller** using **PIP**:

```
C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Code>pip install pyinstaller
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\__main__.py", line 26, in <module>
    sys.exit(_main())
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 73, in main
    command = create_command(cmd_name, isolated=("--isolated" in cmd_args))
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\__init__.py", line 104, in create_command
    module = importlib.import_module(module_path)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.req_command import RequirementCommand, with_cleanup
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pip._internal.index.package_finder import PackageFinder
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\package_finder.py", line 21, in <module>
    from pip._internal.index.collector import parse_links
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\collector.py", line 14, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import html5lib, requests
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\__init__.py", line 114, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\utils.py", line 27, in <module>
    from ._internal_utils import to_native_string
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\_internal_utils.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .compat import is_py2, builtin_str, str
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\compat.py", line 65, in <module>
    from http.cookies import Morsel
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 779, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 915, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 973, in get_data
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Comment: try: `python -m pip install pyinstaller`

Comment: Quite a popular error recently: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bpip%5d%20OSError%20Errno%209%20Bad%20file%20descriptor

Answer (score 0):

If hippozhipos's comment does not work, you could try to install Python from [www.python.org](http://www.python.org) instead of the Microsoft Store. Make sure to tick the "add python to PATH" box in the installation process.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using python 3.8

try: `py -3.8 -m pip install pyinstaller`

This worked for me when I had a similar problem.

if you're installing this in a virtual environment, you can also do:

```
PathToVirtualEnv\Scripts\Python -m pip install pyinstaller
```